# Form Recognizer S0 tier limitations

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

When building a project with the Form Recognizer v. 2.0 API, I get an page limit error when trying to train with more than 500 pages in the project, even though the service has been configured to use tier S0.

Are there limitations on this level or is it because the service is in preview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I find the right documentation for this point, but I agree, it was not easy to find it.

It's here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/overview#input-requirements

It states that, for a custom model:

> PDF and TIFF documents must be 200 pages or less, and the total size
> of the training data set must be 500 pages or less.

So I guess yes this is a limitation, but I don't know if it is due to the preview or not.